# Make flex item fill available space when other children are removed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have multiple children inside a parent with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`.

There is a toggle control on the page which will remove one of the children.

I want the table height to take up all the remaining space if any of the children are removed.

```css
.parent {
  border: black 1px solid;
  height: 260px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  padding: 5px;
}

#table {
  display: table;
  height: 160px;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  border: #000000 solid 1px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child3
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div id="table">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 1, <br />Column 1</div>
        <div class="td">Row 1, Column 2</div>
        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 2, <br />Column 1</div>

        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
        <div class="td">Row 2, Column 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flex-child-height-p60x1)

Currently, if we remove Child2, then the table moves up but height doesn't adjust. The table content has a scroll as well.

Comment: FYI you have a partial property in `.child {}` -- the `align` bit.

Comment: there's an issue with the css for `.child`: The second line `align` isn't valid css

Comment: @TylerH, it wasn't removed erroneously. Was a judgement call. And I hadn't seen the comments. No prob.

Comment: I used the term 'erroneously' because it was an incorrect thing to edit, not because I thought you did it by mistake. Invalid code may be the reason OP's code isn't working... we should always let OP clarify/fix code errors themselves in those cases.

Comment: Mostly agree. But what if the invalid code is clearly just a typo and has nothing to do with the problem as described in the post? That's why I felt it was a judgement call. @TylerH

Comment: Edited, thanks for pointing that out. @MichaelBenjamin, yes that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Give flexibility to the items, so they can stretch to fill available space.

```css
 .parent {
   border: black 1px solid;
   height: 260px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }

 .child {
   padding: 5px;
 }
 
 .child:last-child {
   flex-grow: 1; /* consume available space */
   
   /* give flexibility to child (table element) */
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }

 #table {
   display: table;
   /* height: 160px; */
   height: 100%; /* full height, but will not overflow container because of
                    default flex-shrink: 1 */
 }

 .tr {
   display: table-row;
   padding: 5px;
 }

 .td {
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 150px;
   border: #000000 solid 1px;
   margin: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child1</div>
  <div class="child">Child2</div>
  <div class="child">Child3</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div id="table">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 1, <br />Column 1</div>
        <div class="td">Row 1, Column 2</div>
        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 2, <br />Column 1</div>
        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
        <div class="td">Row 2, Column 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child1</div>
  <div class="child">Child2</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div id="table">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 1, <br />Column 1</div>
        <div class="td">Row 1, Column 2</div>
        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 2, <br />Column 1</div>
        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
        <div class="td">Row 2, Column 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child1</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div id="table">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 1, <br />Column 1</div>
        <div class="td">Row 1, Column 2</div>
        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 2, <br />Column 1</div>
        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
        <div class="td">Row 2, Column 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The table height can't adjust by itself as you have set a fixed height.

You can use `justify-content: space-around` or between on the parent, or you can add flex:1 to the .child elements to keep items spaced out.

You can set the table to height 100% to fill the space. You will also likely have to take the .child wrapper off the table.

```css
.parent {
  border: black 1px solid;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}
#table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  /* height:160px; */
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  border: #000000 solid 1px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child3
  </div>

  <div id="table">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Row 1, <br />Column 1</div>
      <div class="td">Row 1, Column 2</div>
      <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Row 2, <br />Column 1</div>

      <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
      <div class="td">Row 2, Column 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know who is voting all the posts down, but just FYI it is better for you to include your code in the post itself rather than only including a link to an off-site code sandbox.

Comment: I figured it was the person who asked the question voting them down but I don't know. All solutions were pretty much the same and achieved the desired result. I just modified the codesandbox the OP posted. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `flex: 0 1 100%;` on the `.child` elements, you can force them to take all available space, so the `div.child` containing the table will take the full height of the parent if there's no other `.child` divs. Also, your table has a fixed height of `160px`, to make it as big as it's parent, change it to `100%`. Or set a `min-height` of `100%`.

```css
.parent {
  border: black 1px solid;
  height: 260px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 0 1 100%; /* force children to take up as much space as possible */
}

#table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%; /* make it as big as its parent */
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  border: #000000 solid 1px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div id="table">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 1, <br />Column 1</div>
        <div class="td">Row 1, Column 2</div>
        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 2, <br />Column 1</div>

        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
        <div class="td">Row 2, Column 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Css property `flex-grow: 0;` on the `.child` Css. For the table only, that will be overridden by the setting in the `.child:last-child` clause.

```js
function toggleChild ( eve ) {
  let s_idButton = (eve.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "button") ? eve.target.id : eve.target.parentNode.id
    , s_idChild = s_idButton.replace("b", "c")
    , e_child = document.querySelector(`#${s_idChild}`)
    , s_state = e_child.style.display
    ;

e_child.style.display = (s_state === "none") ? "flex" : "none";
  document.querySelector(`#${s_idButton} > span`).textContent = (e_child.style.display === "none") ? "Show" : "Hide";
} // toggleChild

function ready ( eve ) {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'))
    .forEach ( (pe_b) => { pe_b.addEventListener( 'click', toggleChild ); } );
} // ready

window.addEventListener( 'load', ready );
```

```css
.parent {
   border: black 1px solid;
   height: 260px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }

 .child {
   padding: 5px;
   flex-grow: 0; /* helps in consuming available space */
 }

 .child:last-child {
   flex-grow: 1; /* consumes available space */

   /* give flexibility to child (table element) */
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }

 #table {
   display: table;
   /* height: 160px; */
   height: 100%; /* full height; will shrink to fit container because of
                    default flex-shrink: 1 */
 }

 .tr {
   display: table-row;
   padding: 5px;
 }

 .td {
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 150px;
   border: #000000 solid 1px;
   margin: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="c1" class="child">
    Child1
  </div>
  <div id="c2" class="child">
    Child2
  </div>
  <div id="c3" class="child">
    Child3
  </div>
  <div id="c4" class="child">
    <div id="table">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 1, <br />Column 1</div>
        <div class="td">Row 1, Column 2</div>
        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 2, <br />Column 1</div>

        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
        <div class="td">Row 2, Column 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="b1"><span>Hide</span> Child #1</button>
<button id="b2"><span>Hide</span> Child #2</button>
<button id="b3"><span>Hide</span> Child #3</button>
```

***Remark***

I (thoroughly) misunderstood OP's requirements in the first answer (by reading too fast ...). Solution corrected.